# Which nameservers to use?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

When I register a domain name within that companies control panel it gives me the option to use their nameservers. Also, my hosting company has different addresses for their name servers.

Both I think will work but is there any advantage to using the domain supplied name servers over the hosting supplied ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While most web hosts have fairly robust systems, not all web hosts have robust DNS servers. By contrast, most all registrars do have robust DNS servers as a requirement to do business. It is not uncommon for someone to use the web host DNS servers over the registrars DNS servers and be disappointed.

As well, it is often far simpler to set-up your DNS records on the registrars systems due to better control panels. In order to use the web host DNS, at least one other step is required. For anyone who is not that familiar with DNS that chooses to use the web host DNS, future confusion as to which DNS servers is the SOA (statement of authority), the web host or registrar, is very common. We get questions related to the confusion here a lot!

Lastly, some web hosts do require that you use their DNS. That is something to check out. If the web host does not require you to use their DNS servers, then I would stick with the registrars DNS for these simple reasons; it is faster, cheaper, simpler, less confusing, performs better, and does not require two fees and accounts just to keep the domain name alive if you chose to go a different route.

Comment: Thanks that's just the explanation I was looking for. So far I've been using the registrar supplied servers so I will most likely continue to do so.

Comment: "it is often far simpler to set-up your DNS records on the registrars systems" - This really depends on how you are managing your hosting and what you want to do. If you are using something like cPanel or Plesk (and you are using the DNS at your host) then you may not even need to touch the DNS manually at all since the host/control panel will do it all for you (subdomains, addon domains, parked domains, MX, spf records, etc.)

Comment: @w3dk I realize what you are saying. Too many get very confused if they are new to the net. Unless they understand DNS, more in particular SOA, I have seen much better success keeping it simple. As well, most people have just one or two sites that require set-up once. My use of *it is often far simpler* really applies to the newbie and not to the experienced or even familiar. Also, there are hosts that are also registrars, opinions aside on how well that works, making the whole question moot. ;-) Cheers!! Your point is perfectly valid.

Comment: See also the answer by @RocketNuts. I would very rarely use registrar's DNS because it's then on you to keep it up to date if anything changes at the host. Some shared hosts migrate servers/change IPs from time to time, and while they should always send notification of this, it's generally out of the scope of a new user's understanding to update this.

Comment: @TimMalone I do not disagree. I used to be a web host and was the SOA for most all of the domains I hosted, however, I did have a more robust set of servers and networks than tier-1 providers at the time. I took care of it all. In my case, there were no IP address changes. I allocated my IP addresses myself. I go back to how much a user knows, what is easiest, and who has the most robust systems. Both opinions are perfectly valid. I harken back to those who have had difficulty and have come here for help to form my opinion. We have 3 good answers for users to chose from. Cheers!!

Comment: "most all registrars do have robust DNS servers as a requirement to do business. " Pure domain name registrars do not need to run any nameserver for their business, so they may not provide any hosting in that regard to their customers. Of course nowadays pure domain name registrars do not exist and they all provide extra services, sometimes DNS hosting. Just the fact that they are registrars does not make their DNS hosting solution better, or worse, than any other.

Answer (score 2):

All valid points in closetnoc's answer, however, a caveat to consider is that if you use the DNS at your domain's registrar and host/email elsewhere then you will *need* to manually configure all the DNS (`A`, `CNAME`, `MX` ...) records yourself.

Providing you are using a web hosting control panel like cPanel or Plesk then having the DNS managed by your webhost could mean that you'd never need to actually touch the DNS yourself (apart from setting the NAMESERVERS in the first instance).

Answer (score 2):

I most definitely prefer to the host's nameserver whenever possible. In case of a server change (e.g. hardware upgrade) or anything else that could cause an IP change, they can update the DNS settings automatically. If your DNS is configured externally (e.g. with your registrar) you'd have to do that manually, or risking downtime.

Comment: +1 this. The only reason to use a registrar's DNS is if you have a fancy self-hosting set up, can't modify the DNS at your host, or your host doesn't have very redundant DNS (eg. they host all nameservers on the same machine)